# In angular 4 -how to show changed image from one component to another component

Tags: angular

Here I am facing issue like, when i changed the image in profile component its not getting change in nav bar component. I am getting image data in nav bar component but its not changing in html view . when i refresh page image is getting change 
 in navbar ts:

```
export class navbarComponent implements OnInit{

   ImageObject:any =[];
    token: any = window.localStorage.getItem('app_token');

  constructor( public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     console.log("called");
      this.accountService.currentUser().subscribe(
        resval => {
            console.log(resval);
            if(resval.profilePic != undefined){
              this.ImageObject['bs64'] = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpeg;base64,'+resval.profilePic);
              this.ImageObject['uniqnm'] = resval.uniqueName;
              console.log(this.ImageObject);
            }
            else{
                this.ImageObject['bs64'] = '/assets/images/avatar-2.jpg';
                  this.ImageObject['uniqnm'] = "";
                  console.log(this.ImageObject);
            }

          },
        error=>console.log(Error),
        ()=>{

        });
      } 

in navbar html:

img [src]=ImageObject.bs64 width="30px;">
```

Comment: Post the code of both components, show us what you have tried yourself

Comment: I downvoted because [It's hard to answer a programming question without code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you handle your components.

Let's say your fetch your image URL from a back-end, and you have 2 components : **toolbar** and **profile picture changer**.

In your changer, when the user asks to change his picture, you should have

```
this.myService.ChangePP(newUrl).subscribe(data => {/* ... */});
```

In this case, you just **update your database**, not your front-end.

If you want to update your toolbar, you have to **notify the component that your picture has changed**.

For that, you could use a service with a subject that you can subscribe to. Once your picture is changed, you notify the observers, and your image will change accordingly !

Comment: i am getting image in console but in html its not rendering ..<img [src]=imagedata />

Comment: Damn son, I spent 15 minutes making a good explanation and you didn't even bother to read it. Make an effort maybe ?

Comment: Oh yes ? How ? Please explain to me what you did, because you didn't even supply code

Comment: So you tried my method with 2 components, while you have only one ... I'm sorry but I give up there.

Comment: in another component i have some code related to ng2 file upload ,through that i am uploading images ..i am getting every thing but not changing view in navbar component

Comment: Then maybe you could give us the code used in your second component ?